# Inline for in expression evaluation

Tags: python, syntax, for-loop, list-comprehension

Is there a way I could inline this for loop?

```
already_inserted = True
for i in indexes:
    already_inserted = already_inserted and bitfield[i]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
already_inserted = all(bitfield[i] for i in indexes)
```

Answer (score 10):

How about:

```
already_inserted = all(bitfield[i] for i in indexes)
```

Comment: There are two advantages of the `all` function: 1) it will *short-circuit* the computation and stop iterating when the first `False` value is found and 2) it's built-in so the iteration runs entirely in the C code in the Python VM.

Answer (score 1):

all() function accepts iterable and will automatically go over all elements and apply bool to each of them. Therefore, it is sufficient to write:

```
already_inserted = all(bitfield)
```